# Get height of non-overflowed portion of div

Tags: javascript, height, overflow, offset

Say I have a wrapper div with a `overflow:hidden` on it and a div inside that that spans far below the visible portion. How can I get the visible height of the internal div?

```
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow: hidden; height:400px;">
    <div id="inner">
        <!--Lots of content in here-->
    </div>
<div>
```

Every method I try attempting to get the height of the inner div returns the complete height including the hidden parts, i.e. 2000px. I want to be able to get the height of only the visible portion, so 400px in this example case.

I know I could just get the height of the `parentNode`, but in production, the inner div might not be a first child. So there might be other divs separating them, and so the height of `#inner` would be 400 - whatever the offsets of the elements between it and `#wrapper`.

Comment: Ya...i'm thinking I could traverse the dom up until I find an overflow hidden tag. But others might also have this...I dunno. Gotta rack my brain unless others come up with a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As basic algorithm this could work:

```
var offset = 0;
var node = document.getElementById("inner");
while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent.id != "wrapper")
{
    offset += node.offsetTop;
    node = node.offsetParent;
}
var visible = node.offsetHeight - offset;
```

But if you're doing these kinds of things, maybe you already use jQuery, which might be of service with its `.height()` and `.offset()` functions:

```
$("#wrapper").height()-
$("#inner").offset()['top']+
$("#wrapper").offset()['top'];
```

Comment: is it bad idea to use window.getComputedStyle(node).height

Comment: @KishoreRelangi For one, it doesn't work with overflow http://jsfiddle.net/b5DGj/361/

Answer (score 3):

Quick algorithm that goes up the DOM tree looking at `window.getComputedStyle` for `overflow: hidden`

```
function visibleArea(node){
    var o = {height: node.offsetHeight, width: node.offsetWidth}, // size
        d = {y: (node.offsetTop || 0), x: (node.offsetLeft || 0), node: node.offsetParent}, // position
        css, y, x;
    while( null !== (node = node.parentNode) ){  // loop up through DOM
        css = window.getComputedStyle(node);
        if( css && css.overflow === 'hidden' ){  // if has style && overflow
            y = node.offsetHeight - d.y;         // calculate visible y
            x = node.offsetWidth - d.x;          // and x
            if( node !== d.node ){
                y = y + (node.offsetTop || 0);   // using || 0 in case it doesn't have an offsetParent
                x = x + (node.offsetLeft || 0);
            }
            if( y < o.height ) {
                if( y < 0 ) o.height = 0;
                else o.height = y;
            }
            if( x < o.width ) {
                if( x < 0 ) o.width = 0;
                else o.width = x;
            }
            return o;                            // return (modify if you want to loop up again)
        }
        if( node === d.node ){                   // update offsets
            d.y = d.y + (node.offsetTop || 0);
            d.x = d.x + (node.offsetLeft || 0);
            d.node = node.offsetParent;
        }
    }
    return o;                                    // return if no hidden
}
```

example [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mXc5H/) (look at your console).

Comment: Note, it doesn't take into account the scroll location.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do this in every circumstance, including when there's overflow, `transform: translate()`s are used, and there are other nested containers in between an element and the element that's hiding its overflow is to combine `.getBoundingClientRect()` with a reference to the ancestor that's hiding the element's overflow:

```
function getVisibleDimensions(node, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode = referenceNode || node.parentNode;

    var pos = node.getBoundingClientRect();
    var referencePos = referenceNode.getBoundingClientRect();

    return {
        "width": Math.min(
            node.clientWidth,
            referencePos.left + referenceNode.clientWidth - pos.left, 
            node.clientWidth - (referencePos.left - pos.left)
        ),
        "height": Math.min(
            node.clientHeight, 
            referencePos.top + referenceNode.clientHeight - pos.top,
            node.clientHeight - (referencePos.top - pos.top)
        )
    }
}
```

## [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/obpez4qd/3/).

If a reference node is not given, the parent node is assumed: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/obpez4qd/4/).

Note that this doesn't take into account whether or not an element is viewable *in the viewport*, just visible (not hidden due to overflow). If you need both, you can combine functionality with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/442474/2065702). It also has no check of `visibility: hidden`, so if you need that you need to check the `style.visibility` property of the node and all its ancestors.

Answer (score -1):

I think keeping a sibling next to it, calculating its scrollTop and the overflow element scrollTop and then subtracting it from the siblings scroolTop might work

Comment: This is nothing to do with scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

The code below computes the visible portion of an element. By visible portion I mean the part that is visible in the **window**, but I think you can easily alter it to base the computation on an arbitrary container element.

```
function computeVisibleHeight ($t) {
        var top = $t.position().top;
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var height = $t.height();

        if (top < scrollTop && height - scrollTop >= windowHeight) {
            // first case: the top and the bottom of the element is outside of the window
            return windowHeight;
        } else if (top < scrollTop) {
            // second: the top is outside of the viewport but the bottom is visible
            return height - (scrollTop - top);
        } else if (top > scrollTop && top + height < windowHeight) {
            // the whole element is visible
            return height;
        } else {
            // the top is visible but the bottom is outside of the viewport
            return windowHeight - (top - scrollTop);
        }
    }
```

The code is using jquery.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. Question does not deal with the viewport.