# How to I calculate the height of visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html page like the following model,

when user is scrolling the page,  how to I calculate the height of visible part of the #page1?

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 #heder (position: fixed; height: 100px, z-index: 10)
-------------------------------------------------------

                     visible zone

 ____________________________________________________
 |                                                  |
 |                  #page1 (visible)                |
 |                                                  |
 |  (position: static; height: 1000px, z-Index: 0)  |
 |                                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------
 #footer (position: fixed; height: 50px, z-index: 10)
-------------------------------------------------------
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                  #page1 (invisible)              |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 ____________________________________________________
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                  #page2 (invisible)              |
 |                                                  |
 |  (position: static; height: 700px, z-Index: 0)   |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 |                                                  |
 ____________________________________________________
```

Comment: I think this has what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868287/get-height-of-visible-portion-of-div

Answer (score 1):

you can get the height of the outermost window by using `window.top` in the jQuery. The height of `window.top` will get the height of the browser window or iframe inside it.

```
$(window.top).height();
```